# How to show that $f:S^1 \to S^1,f(z) = z^2$ is a local diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry

How to show that $f:S^1 \to S^1,f(z) = z^2$ is a local diffeomorphism?

To show it is a local diffeomorphism, I need to check that it is $f$ is both a immersion and a submersion. Then I need to choose charts of $S^1$ and compute the Jacobian of the coordinate representaion of $f$ to find that it is actually invertible at every point. Is this the usual way to approach this problem?

Comment: Yup, that's how you do that. Here you've apparently embedded $S^1$ into the complex plane and are considering a map that extends to the whole plane, so you don't have to pick charts for $S^1$, but just check the differential of $f$ at all points of the image of the embedding.

Comment: I am a little confused, can you give me more details?

Comment: $df = 2zdz$. This is nonzero on the unit circle, and thus an isomorphism as your tangent space is one-one-dimensional.